# React.js IF statement only returning first condition

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a function that chooses which icon to display based on when memType is passed through:

```
const renderAvatar = (memType) => {
    if ((memType = "Music")) {
        return <MusicIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "Movie")) {
        return <MovieIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "TVShow")) {
        return <TVIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "Game")) {
        return <GameIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "Event")) {
        return <EventIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    }
}
```

However, it is only returning the icon of whichever condition is at the top (the MusicIcon in the above example). For example, it would only display the MovieIcon if that was the first condition:

```
const renderAvatar = (memType) => {
        return <MovieIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "TVShow")) {
    if ((memType = "Music")) {
        return <MusicIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "Movie")) {
        return <TVIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "Game")) {
        return <GameIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType = "Event")) {
        return <EventIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    }
}
```

I have checked that the `memType` data being passed through is correct and it is and can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are using a single `=` sign, which is the _assignment_ operator.  To check equality in JS, use `==` for loose equality or `===` for strict-equality.

Comment:  Sorry, such a rookie mistake! Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: For those attempting to close as a typo, I'd assert that this is a relatively common mistake made among people just getting started in programming or with a particular language.  I know I made this mistake a few times myself early on in my programming life.  Other's experiencing this same symptom might discover this post and find it helpful.  It isn't like flubbing a variable name or misspelling the word `function`, both of which I would consider "typos".  Just my two cents.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single `=` sign, which is the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment). To check equality in JS, use [`==` for loose equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) or [`===` for strict-equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (preferred).

```js
const renderAvatar = (memType) => {
    if ((memType === "Music")) {
        return <MovieIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType === "TVShow")) {
    if ((memType === "Music")) {
        return <MusicIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType === "Movie")) {
        return <TVIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType === "Game")) {
        return <GameIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    } else if ((memType === "Event")) {
        return <EventIcon style={{ color: 'white' }} />
    }
}
```